# Accidentally deleted the Git Shell shortcut

Tags: github-for-windows

So where is it? I checked the usual suspects, namely Program Files and Program Files (x86), but I didn't see any mention of GitHub there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know someone offered an answer but deleted it for whatever reason before I could accept it, so here goes.

You need to create a shortcut to a command, which is actually rather convoluted.

1. Right-click on the desktop and do New > Shortcut
2. Browse to any file, **but make sure it's not a .exe file!!**
3. Click next through the rest of the wizard and accept the defaults
4. Now right-click the shortcut, go to Properties > Shortcut tab
5. Set the Target to: "C:\Documents and Settings\\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms" --open-shell
6. In step 5 above, the quotes are required.

Comment: If you use a .exe file for step 2, when you get to step 4 you'll notice that there's no Shortcut tab. That confused the crap out of me, but apparently it's a Windows thing. Whatever.

Comment: on windows 7 i ended up using a target of "%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell"

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is to run

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --reinstall-shortcuts
```

which will recreate the shortcut on the desktop.